# Inner join constraint using clustered indexing (need the nulls)

Tags: sql, sql-server, clustered-index

I've create a clustered indexed view and it reduces the query time by 4x. The main problem is that I cannot use full outer joins while doing so, ending up losing up to 20% of records of my dataset (nulls are important for posterior transformations).

Is there a way to keep the nulls while using the inner join?

I've tried a couple of things and none of them worked:

1. ```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.gbmp mp 
   INNER JOIN
   dbo.gbnatr ntr
   ON ISNULL(mp.GBMPNATR,-1) = ntr.NTNATR
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.gbmp mp 
   INNER JOIN
   dbo.gbnatr ntr
   ON mp.GBMPNATR = ntr.NTNATR OR ntr.NTNATR IS NULL
   ```

This is my index definition:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_STG_Movements_Prec_DO_norn
 on STG_Movements_Prec_DO (GBMPNOPR,GBMPNORN,GBMPNSEQN,GBMPNDOC,GBMPVLR)
```

Is there a workaround?

```
Inputs:

Table gbmp
OPR | Natr 
 1  | DO
 2  | DO
 3  | CC
 4  | CRF

Table gbnatr
OPR | Natr 
 1  | DO
 2  | DO
 3  | CC
 4  | EFT

Desired output:

OPR | Natr 
 1  | DO
 2  | DO
 3  | CC
 4  | NULL

Output obtained:

OPR | Natr 
 1  | DO
 2  | DO
 3  | CC
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Are the `NULL`s in the data or produced by the `full join`?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` to `dbo.gbnatr` and *not* use `ISNULL` and `IS NULL` in the `ON`? Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the NULL produced by a left join I use on the original query. The queries I posted here are used on VIEW creation only

Comment: @Larnu it is a clustered view. I'm a newbie but as far as my knowledge goes, I cannot use left joins in Schemabinding clustered views, right?

Comment: This is why I've asked for sample data, and expected results, @mburns. Without knowing what you are actually after we have to guess.

Comment: @Larnu sorry. I've added some sample data and expected outputs

Comment: Can't you simply create a regular index instead?

Comment: @jarlh how do I create one? Just like this:                                                         
CREATE INDEX IX_STG_Movements_Prec_DO_norn
on STG_Movements_Prec_DO (GBMPNOPR,GBMPNORN,GBMPNSEQN,GBMPNDOC,GBMPVLR)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `NULL` values in the data and want an *inner join*, then you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.gbmp mp JOIN
     dbo.gbnatr ntr
     ON mp.GBMPNATR = ntr.NTNATR
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.gbmp mp JOIN
     dbo.gbnatr ntr
     ON mp.GBMPNATR IS NULL AND nt.NTNATR IS NULL;
```

This should use appropriate indexes on the columns.

EDIT:

You seem to want:

```
SELECT mp.OPR,
       (CASE WHEN mp.Natr = ntr.Natr THEN mp.Natr END) as Natr
FROM dbo.gbmp mp JOIN
     dbo.gbnatr ntr
     ON mp.OPR = ntr.OPR
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't get the desired output

Comment: @mburns . .  That seems like simple `case` logic with a `join`.

Comment: That won't do it either. I think I've explained myself wrongly, but thank you for your insights